# How to get image of barcode?

Tags: android

I am using ZXing api to read barcode from a image and i can read barcode using below code but i want also image of barcode which capture by api please let me know how to get it.

IntentIntegrator.initiateScan(Activity);

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Guy,

I guess that my answer is late..

You can implement the capture() method in camera factory.
Remember that you'll have to describe where you want to save this "DATA PHOTO" or simply "PHOTO"
(Normaly, you'll save that in SDCard)